# How to use PyO3 custom module in production

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I have created a custom module in rust and converted it to a python module using PyO3 binding. It works on a local machine using the hardcoded route, unlike other packages where it only has a name.   I understand other packages are launched in PIP so they can be downloaded anywhere. But is it possible that I can use my custom package in production?
I haven't tried it yet because I know it won't work, since dependencies need to be available in PIP to be able to download it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

The PyO3 project maintains a tool called [maturin](https://maturin.rs/) whose purpose is to help publish pyo3 or mixed python/pyo3 project to pypi.

That is probably the simplest way of publishing to pypi such that `pip install` can find the package.

The PyO3 documentation also [has a publication page](https://pyo3.rs/main/building_and_distribution.html).